# Form is sending nil values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm having problems when submitting a form in rails, the problem is that the controller receive the values as nil.

I have an orders_controller:

```
def new
    @order = Order.new
    @order.total_without_discounts = 0
    @order.total_with_discounts = 0
    @cart.items.each do |item|
        orderProduct = OrderProduct.new
        orderProduct.count = item.count 
        orderProduct.product = item.product 
        orderProduct.discount = calculate_discounts(item)
        @order.total_with_discounts += item.total - (orderProduct.discount * item.count)
        @order.total_without_discounts += item.total
        @order.order_products << orderProduct
    end
    
end

def create

    @order = Order.new(params[:order])
   
   
    if(@order.save)
        @cart.clear
        redirect_to root_path,notice: "Order succesfully loaded, thank you for choosing us."

    else
        redirect_to root_path,notice: "Ooops! Something went wrong, try again in a few seconds."
    end
end
```

The new method is workig well because i can see the data on the related view.

But then i have a form that only have a submit button, because all the data is loaded in the new method.

new order view :

```
...

<%= form_with(model: @order) do |form| %>
      <div class="mt-6">
        <%= form.submit "Confirm ", class: "flex justify-center items-center px-6 py-3 border border-transparent rounded-md shadow-sm text-base font-medium text-white bg-indigo-600 hover:bg-indigo-700"%>
          
      </div>
      <%end%>
...
```

When i press submit the order is saved but the log show that the values are nil :

```
 TRANSACTION (0.9ms)  BEGIN
byebuy-web-1  |   ↳ app/controllers/orders_controller.rb:34:in `create'
byebuy-web-1  |   Order Create (1.6ms)  INSERT INTO "orders" ("total_with_discounts", "total_without_discounts", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["total_with_discounts", nil], ["total_without_discounts", nil], ["created_at", "2022-02-28 19:17:41.681687"], ["updated_at", "2022-02-28 19:17:41.681687"]]
byebuy-web-1  |   ↳ app/controllers/orders_controller.rb:34:in `create'
byebuy-web-1  |   TRANSACTION (2.7ms)  COMMIT
byebuy-web-1  |   ↳ app/controllers/orders_controller.rb:34:in `create'
byebuy-web-1  | Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
byebuy-web-1  | Completed 302 Found in 67ms (ActiveRecord: 5.2ms | Allocations: 2833)
```

I've tried with strong params to but the problem continues.
What i'm missing here ?

Comment: Rails is creating a new instance of a controller per each request, so the controller that handled your `new` action is different instance that the one that is to handle `create`. As such they do not share any data between them. Your form has no fields, so it is not sending any additional information - if you want it to do so, you need to add hidden_fields, but this will be very silly, security-wise, This mean you have to repeat your order object setup in create action as well - this is usually done via a before_action hook for Dryiness

Comment: @BroiSatse I would argue that complex buisness logic like this doen't belong in a private function in a controller. It belongs somewhere where it can be tested in isolation.

Comment: @max - Oh, absolutely. But it would take way much space than it is available per comment here to get into "how to do it properly" and "how RailsWay(tm) is plainly wrong" :P